# How to display index during list iteration with Django?

Tags: python, django

I am passing a list to a view. My array looks like this: `[football, basketball, soccer]`. In my view, I would like to display something like this:

```
1. football
2. basketball
3. soccer
```

This means that I would have to iterate through the list that is passed to the array, do a for loop on the elements. How would I do this in the template file?

For each element, I would have to get its index and add 1 to it. Now, I have no idea how to do this in the views. One way I thought about doing this would be to make a dictionary, like so, `{'1', 'football': '2', 'basketball': '3', 'soccer'}`, but since I already have the data in a list format, I would rather not convert it.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You want the [forloop.counter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#for) template variable.

> The for loop sets a number of variables available within the loop:
>
> **forloop.counter**   The current iteration of the loop (1-indexed)

So your code would look like:

```
{% for sport in sports %}
    <p>{{forloop.counter}}. {{ sport }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Of course, for simply displaying the data as you do in your question, the easier way is just to show the items in an ordered list, and the browser will do the numbering for you:

```
<ol>
{% for sport in sports %}
    <li>{{ sport }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ol>
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer from @nrabinowitz is a good solution if you want to use it in a template. But I think you were asking to do that from a view.

The best way to get the index and value from a list is using the `enumerate` function, like this:

```
>>> sports = ['football', 'basketball', 'soccer']
>>> for i,sport in enumerate(sports):
...     print "%d. %s" % (i, sport)
0. football
1. basketball
2. soccer
```

Or, if you want a 1-based index:

```
>>> for i,sport in enumerate(sports):
...     print "%d. %s" % (i+1, sport)
1. football
2. basketball
3. soccer
```

Comment: You are telling it in python. But can this be used in Django? Please answer from Django template point of view?

Answer (score 1):

courtesy of the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8088095/5719810) above

If someone needs to use a condition of the loop iteration count, he can use this block of code.

`2` is used for illustration of an `integer`.

```
{% if forloop.counter == 2 %}
do something what you want for second iteration
{% endfor %}
```